# For every 2 queries we are reducing the search space by 25%. How many total queries needed to exhaust the entire search space

Tags: math

Assume that we have a search space consisting of numbers from 1 to 10^9. For every 2 queries we are reducing the search space by 25%. What will be the total number of queries required to completely exhaust the search space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to solve this equation for n:

```
1 = 10^9 * (3/4)^(n/2)
```

Here we go

```
1 = 10^9 * (3/4)^(n/2)
1/10^9 = (3/4)^(n/2)
10^9 = (4/3)^(n/2)
log_(4/3) 10^9 = n/2
n = 2 * log_(4/3) 10^9
```

looks like n = 144 is pretty close. We can check that: n/2 = 72 and (3/4)^72 = 1.0102083739526135305448424868787e-9 and 10^9 * 1.0102083739526135305448424868787e-9 = 1.0102083739526135305448424868787

Now, you might object that this is not exactly equal to one, and that generally this ignores effects of rounding. However, the problem as stated does the same, since the search space cannot decrease by exactly 25% more than a few times before you'd start getting fractional numbers of items - in other words, it doesn't decrease by exactly 25% every time anyway. If you wanted to be precise, you could say that the search space decreases by as close to 25% as possible at each step, or it increases as much as possible but no more than 25% at each step, etc., and then the method of resolution would be simply to count the number of reductions required while performing the rounding as required.